# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php (Line 179) in wamp

Tags: laravel

I set up a laravel project and installed tzsk payumoney payment gateway in my project and put the index.php and .httdocs file in the root folder from /public folder. Now when i'm running my project on wamp server this is working well but routes of tzsk in vendor folder is not working.

When i run the 'php artisan route:list' it gives me all routes definde in tzsk also.

Please help what i'm missing.

Comment: Thanks for your question. You can help people get this working for you if you can provide more details about your question. Consider posting your routes, the output of your `php artisan route:list`, your modifications to index.php, etc, etc. We're coders, show us the code! :)

Comment: As @Peter already mentioned please share some code. Here are some resources: 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  
https://stackexchange.com/tour